# Concorrencia ao usar tabela temporaria

Tags: microsoft-access, vba

Estou usando um código vba que transfere alguns dados para uma tabela auxiliar, manipula e volta para a tabela original.

Como eu faço para resolver o problema de concorrência? Ou seja, não queria que dois usuários usassem ao mesmo tempo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução genérica, isto é, que não aplica-se somente ao Microsoft Access, é adicionar uma coluna referente ao ID do usuário e fazer referência a esta coluna em todas as queries realizadas na tabela, de modo a permitir que os diferentes usuários atuem simultaneamente, cada um com no máximo uma instância do aplicativo.

Em determinado projeto, minha equipe teve de usar uma tabela "temporária", que na verdade era uma tabela normal, e nós aplicamos estas solução. Criamos um índice adequado para garantir o desempenho e funcionou bem.

---

Outra abordagem que efetivamente bloqueia concorrência é realizar as operações dentro de uma transação, cujo primeiro comando é de limpar toda a tabela. Ao realizar essa limpeza, o sistema de banco de dados vai bloquear outros processos que tentarem realizar a mesma operação até que a transação seja concluída.

Nesse cenário, um usuário que tentasse executar a operação enquanto outro já estivesse executando teria que aguardar o término da transação atual.

Comment: As duas respostas me foram úteis, obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 1):

Soluções possíveis:

1 - Tem um flag em alguma tabela (tabela principal, tabela temporária, ou qualquer outra tabela do seu sistema) que indique que a tabela temporária está em uso ou está livre

2 - Fazer com que esta tarefa só possa ser desempenhada por um código, e o código manter o controle se a tabela está em uso ou não (como se fosse um semáforo ou um singleton) - provavelmente vai precisar armazenar este estado em uma tabela também

3 - Criar uma coluna extra na tabela temporária para sinalizar qual usuário / processo está utilizando quais registros, e fazer com que todo o resto do código respeite este registro

4 - Dividir o arquivo MDB fazendo com que a tabela temporária rode localmente no computador de cada usuário (fonte: http://www.accessfaq.com.br/webroot/default.asp?http%3A//www.accessfaq.com.br/webroot/detalhe.asp%3FPergunta_Id%3D23)

> É melhor dividir o mdb em dois arquivos: um, contendo as tabelas (back-end) que fica no diretório compartilhado da rede; e o outro, contendo as tabelas vinculadas, consultas, formulários, macros e módulos (front-end) que fica em cada estação de trabalho. Leia a resposta à pergunta Como dividir o banco de dados e trabalhar com tabelas vinculadas?, do assunto "Tabelas", para obter maiores detalhes.